# Probability distribution from mean time to failure

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> A factory has different categories of machines which require frequent
>   adjustments and repair. Each category of machine fails uniformly after
>   continuous operation and the failure profile of the different
>   categories of machines is given by its mean time to failure (MTTF).

With the above information I need to assume a probability distribution for their failure profiles. So what are the meaningful/safe assumptions that I should make about the distribution?What actually do we know about machines when we know their MTTF and that they fail uniformly after continuous operation?

Comment: you may assume constant hazard rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fail uniformly" probably means that they fail at a constant rate (with a different rate for each type of machine). Uniformly is not a good word in this context as it implies the machine failure time follows a uniform distribution (this would be roughly the same number of machines failing in every time period, which is not realistic).
Failing at a constant rate $\lambda$ per unit time happens when the number of fails X in the interval from 0 to t (so $\lambda$t fails on average) follows a Poisson distribution

$P(X = k) = \frac{{{(\lambda t)}^{k}}\exp (-\lambda t)}{k!}$

If roughly half of these machines have failed up to some time $t_0$ then half of the remaining will fail in the next interval up to $t_0$ and so on, decreasing all the time. If T is the time to failure of a machine, which is a random variable, then the probability that the machine is still working after time t is the same as the probability that X is 0 i.e. there has been no fail up to time t. Then

$P(T>t) = P(X = 0) = \exp (-\lambda t)$

This is the Reliability of the machine type, which is the proportion of machines which are still working after time t. The failure rate $\lambda$ is 1/MTTF for that type of machine. So for a given MTTF we can work out the proportion of machines which will fail up to time t using the reliability.
e.g If lightbulbs have a MTTF of 300hrs then the proportion which are still working after 200hrs is

$exp(-\frac{1}{300}*200) = 0.513$ or 51%

The proportion which have failed up to time t is 1 - Reliability. This can be written as an integral up to time t of the probability density for T. Differentiation will then give the density for the variable T, but the Reliability is a more meaningful thing to focus on for practical purposes.

Comment: what about weibull distribution??

Comment: The weibull distribution is used to model the reliability over the complete lifetime of a product. Typically, the early life and late life of a product is subject to higher (time dependent)failure rates than its so called normal life. I interpreted your question as asking about the normal life of the product, where the exponential distribution is appropriate. A suitably chosen Weibull distribution can also fit this normal life period.